# How to get page's static resource URL string using JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, static-resources

I want to get URL string of Salesforce static resource in JavaScript code.

Something like:

```
var url = getURL('static_resource_name')
```

Is there a method to capture this from a page using JS?

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you mean by "without having ability to modify VF page"?

Comment: @KeithC, I mean is it possible to get the URL without having to edit VF page. I want to get the url form script that is referenced in VF page.

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean. You can have the URL output in the JavaScript or in the visible text of the page and you can include JavaScript that transfers it between the two. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I don understand how can {!$Resource.staticResourceName} be evaluated in the JavaScript code. I think of it as VF merge syntax which is evaluated on server side only as part of VF page.

Comment: What arrives in the browser is what was evaluated at the server. Then the JavaScript runs in the browser. Use you browser's "View Source" or "Inspect Element" to see what the browser receives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use html input hidden tag as:

```
<input type="hidden" id="stresource" value="{!$Resource.staticResourceName}"/>

<script>

    var resource_url = document.getElementById('stresource').value;

    // direct way:
    var diret_url = '{!$Resource.staticResourceName}';

</script>
```

Comment: Is {!$Resource.staticResourceName} evaluated on client side ?

Comment: Yes @MatkoKlaic on client side it will change into url

Comment: @MatkoKlaic The `{!$Resource.staticResourceName}` is evaluated on the server side and the resulting URL text will be present in the HTML page where the client-side JavaScript can make use of it. That is normally sufficient to allow most logic to be implemented.